# How to add chilkatsoft into netbeans java

Tags: java

i want to use chilkatsoft Component in my project and i read install at [link](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/installJavaWindows.asp), but i don't understand how to add it in netbeans. Please help me step by step install it.

Comment: Really?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a Java Application Project within Netbeans.
2. Expand that Projects node in the Projects Tab on the left.
3. Right-click the Libraries Folder.
4. In pop-up menu choose "Add Jar/Folder ..."
5. Select the chilkat.jar file you downloaded.
6. Right click the Project's main node and choose properties.
7. Select Run in the Categories List on the left.
8. In text field for VM Options and an option to put the directory with chilkat.dll on java library path ( eg. -Djava.library.path=/home/shackle/chilkatJava-9.5.0-jdk8-x86-linux )
9. Test the setup by copying the code from supplied Test.java file into your projects main Java file and using Shift-F6 with that file selected to run.

That code was:

```
static {
    try {

        System.loadLibrary("chilkat");

    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

// Instantiate a Chilkat object and print it's version.
public static void main(String argv[]) {
    CkZip zip = new CkZip();
    System.out.println(zip.version());
}
```